# Adding form data and rendering to the DOM React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating warehouse management application where I enter data to the form in the form component. When submitting form I want to render entered data to the DOM, in the local storage: `http://localhost:3000/products/`. `changeHandler` works good, I receive data from input fields. However, `addItemHandler` does not work and it does not render anything. Could anybody help me, please.

```
    import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
    import nextId from "react-id-generator";
    
    const ProductContext = createContext();

    class ProductProvider extends Component {
      newId = nextId();

      state = {
        products: [
          { id: "", name: "", ean: "", type: "", weight: "", color: "", quantity: "", price: "", info: "", }, ],
        detailProduct: "",
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        this.setProducts();
      }

      setProducts = () => {
        let products = [];
        this.state.products.forEach((item) => {
          const singleItem = { ...item };
          products = [...products, singleItem];
        });
        this.setState(() => {
          return { products: products };
        });
      };

      getItem = (id) => {
        const product = this.state.products.find((item) => item.id === id);
        return product;
      };

      productDetailHandler = (id) => {
        const product = this.getItem(id);
        this.setState(() => {
          return { detailProduct: product };
        });
      };

      changeHandler = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
          products: { ...this.state.products, [event.target.name]: value },
        });
      };

      addItemHandler = ( event, name, ean, type, weight, color, quantity, price, info ) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const products = [
          ...this.state.products,
          { name, ean, type, weight, color, quantity, price, info, id: this.newID },
        ];
        this.setState({ products: products });
        console.log(this.state);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <ProductContext.Provider
            value={{
              ...this.state,
              productDetailHandler: this.productDetailHandler,
              changeHandler: this.changeHandler,
              addItemHandler: this.addItemHandler,
            }}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </ProductContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }

    const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

    export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

Comment: Can you add this [here](http://react.new/)

Comment: if you send an object that probably try to do so :  { "name": name, "ean": ean,  etc }

Comment: it would be better if you post which component is using the Form

Comment: You sometimes set the state's `products` property to an array and other times to an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
        ...
        newProductItem: {}
      };


// the `products`'s type is an Object Array

changeHandler = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  const {newProductItem} = this.state
  this.setState({
    newProductItem: { ...newProductItem, [event.target.name]: value}
  });
}


addItemHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const {newProductItem} = this.state
  const products = [
     ...this.state.products,
    {...newProductItem, id:this.newID}
  ];
  this.setState({ 
     products, 
     newProductItem: {} 
  });      
};
```

==== in diff page ==

```
// form.jsx
  state = {
        ...
        newProductItem: {}
      };
  ...

  changeHandler = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const { newProductItem } = this.state
    this.setState({
      newProductItem: { ...newProductItem, [event.target.name]: value}
    }); 
  }

  ... 
  render(){
   ...
   const {  addItemHandler} = this.props
   const { newProductItem } = this.state
   <Form submit={(ev)=> {
    addItemHandler(ev, newProductItem); 
    this.setState({newProductItem:{}});
   }>
     <Input onChange={changeHandler} />
   </Form>
  }
  ...
  <>
  ...
```

```
// main.jsx
addItemHandler = (event, newProductItem) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const products = [
     ...this.state.products,
    {...newProductItem, id:this.newID}
  ];
  this.setState({ 
     products
  });      
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220492/discussion-on-answer-by-liu-lei-adding-form-data-and-rendering-to-the-dom-react).